# Hourly average usage in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I can get Application Insights to display a running hourly log of usage, but is there a way to display average usage on an hourly basis to see what times of the day a site is must used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

on the overview blade your resource, isn't there a metrics explorer that shows exactly that?  the last 24 hours by hour?  if that isn't what you mean, you could make an analytics query to get whatever you want, something like

```
requests 
| where timestamp > ago(7d) 
| extend hour = datetime_part("hour", timestamp)
| summarize sum(itemCount)/7 by hour
| order by hour asc
| render barchart
```

which would show you requests over the last 7 days split by each of the 24 hours, divided by 7 to show you average per day.

if you just want "today's" version of that its even simpler:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d) 
| summarize sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

anything you can query in the analytics website you can then pin as a tile on your azure dashboard.

Comment: First, thanks; I didn't know about analytics queries. But that's not quite right; it was hard to explain what I'm looking for. Not hourly bins, but average usage by time of day. I.e., the x-axis should only have 24 values, corresponding to clock hours, and the y-axis shows average usage during that hour. I took your answer and got a bit closer: "pageViews | where timestamp > ago(7d) | summarize count() by datepart("Hour", timestamp) | render barchart", but the sorting of the x-axis is way off. Side note: hourofday is not a known function.

Comment: updated to add some variations and to add `sum(itemCount)` and fix syntax.  if you're doing any kind of sampling, any individual row could be a "group" of rows.

Comment: Thanks! It was the extend operator I was missing. Tried ordering on datepart and couldn't get that to work.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the results will be in UTC.  You can add a local offset by doing something like this:

```requests 
| extend localTimestamp = timestamp - 4h // replace 4 with your local offset from UTC
| where localTimestamp > ago(30d) 
| extend hour = datetime_part("hour", localTimestamp)
| summarize sum(itemCount)/30 by hour
| order by hour asc
| render barchart```